# Trying to compare two listviews and output into a new listview in c#

Tags: c#, listview, comparison

So I am trying to compare two list views, which contain services before an install and services after - I have tried using the below method to do so

```
serviceinfo si = new serviceinfo();
        for (int i = 0; i < listView2.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string testing = listView1.Items[i].Text;
            //MessageBox.Show(testing);
            ListViewItem item = listView2.FindItemWithText(testing);
            //MessageBox.Show(item.ToString());
            if (item == null)
            { 
                //MessageBox.Show("Test");
                si.name = item.Text;
                listView3.Items.Add(si.name);
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Item exists");
            }
        }
```

If I change the "item == null" to "!=" this outputs all equal items - but when it is "==" I get an "Object not referenced error" which I understand refers to trying to set si.name to a null object however i need the text.

Any assistance with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you expect to set a value to something that dose not exist? The "FindItemWithText"  returned null cause there is no item that met your criteria.

Comment: I think it was one of those, I've been looking at it for so long I couldn't see the forest for the trees - after looking at the answer I've marked as correct below obviously I should of been using "testing" not "item.text" as that would essentially be "null.text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to use something like this. Comments in code explain the logic.

```
// Loop over the items in the first list....
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    // Get the text of the item at i pos in the first listview
    string testing = listView1.Items[i].Text;

    // Search it in the second listview
    ListViewItem item = listView2.FindItemWithText(testing);

    // If not found...
    if (item == null)
    { 
        // Add the text to the third listview
        listView3.Items.Add(testing);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Item exists");
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** I suppose that you want to discover if the latest install has added some new services, in this context the code above assumes that the first ListView is the list of services **AFTER** install and the second ListView contains the service **BEFORE** install.

If this is not the case then just reverse the ListView variables names.....
(However I suggest you to give at this objects a more understandable names like lvBeforeInstall, lvAfterInstall, lvAddedServices)

Comment: This actually worked a treat! 


I kept the si.name as that is a class I made for storing it externally later on when the form is reloaded for the purpose that is required.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you can add
    if(listView1.Items.Count < i) return;
to the top of your subroutine. This will avoid the null-ref. 
I would strongly recommend comparing your data in the model instead of the view. It would be worth your time to study MVVM or MVC architecture, and how this problem would be handled in contemporary programming design patterns.

Comment: Sorry, I'm rather new to c# (3 weeks in the making) so what do you mean by the "model instead of the view"? And I will most certainly have a look at the architectures you have mentioned! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Study the MVC design pattern, and all mysteries shall be revealed ;)